# Salesforce to paypal integration

Tags: integration, paypal

please advice to resolve the paypal response error the error is 

   Invalid URL
   The requested URL "/2.0/", is invalid.

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange. At this time your question provides very little context or detail which makes it very hard to know what you're precisely asking or what may be the problem. Could you update your question with more info ?

Answer (score 4):

I know just linking up blog posts is considered poor-answering on SFSE, but with the detail in your question it's hard to compose a specific answer.. I wrote a couple of blog posts on Salesforce -> Paypal integration some time ago that you can find here:

[Salesforce - Paypal Masspay Integration](http://srlawr.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/integrating-paypal-api-with.html)

and

[Salesforce Paypal IPN integration](http://srlawr.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/processing-paypal-ipn-messages-with.html)

The most relevant bit (from the first post) regarding the POST URL contains such advice as:

> Before we can interact with the PayPal servers, you need to grant your organisation access to the Paypal web services. Click Your name -> Setup -> Security Controls -> Remote Site Settings, now add the following site to the list:
>
> Paypal_SOAP:    https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
>
> At this point, we basically have a functioning back end integration with PayPal.

Basically, here, have you added the URL to your remote site settings?

Another gotcha is, are you definitely connecting to the 2.0 URL via HTTPS (ie secure).